# Patching 3.2.4 primefaces

Tags: primefaces

How do I apply a patch to an older version of primefaces? Is there a repository that I can download the source code from or is there a way I can get the code from the source file?

Answer (score 0):

The primefaces svn repository is located at `http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces`. It has all of the source code for the various versions in the tags folder and the latest source code in the trunk folder.